# Get the files inside a directory

Tags: php

How to get the file names inside a directory using PHP?

I couldn't find the relevant command using Google, so I hope that this question will help those who are asking along the similar lines.

Comment: it's a duplicate of so many questions on here.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There's a lot of ways. The older way is [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/scandir) but  [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) is probably the best way.

There's also [`readdir`](http://www.php.net/readdir) (to be used with [`opendir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)) and [`glob`](http://www.php.net/glob).

Here are some examples on how to use each one to print all the files in the current directory:

#### `DirectoryIterator` usage: (recommended)

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) continue;
    print $file->getFilename() . '<br>';
}
```

#### `scandir` usage:

```
$files = scandir('.');
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    print $file . '<br>';
}
```

#### `opendir` and `readdir` usage:

```
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        print $file . '<br>';
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

#### `glob` usage:

```
foreach (glob("*") as $file) {
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    print $file . '<br>';
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, `glob` is nice because the asterisk I used there can actually be used to do matches on the files, so `glob('*.txt')` would get you all the text files in the folder and `glob('image_*')` would get you all files that start with image_

Comment: One advantage of glob is you can filter files easily, for example `glob('*.txt')` will list all text files.

Comment: @EvilChookie: The only thing I can think of is that glob and scandir load the entire file structure into memory automatically, which is just something you should be aware of. Not sure about anything else.

Comment: @EvilChookie: see here some were benchmarked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120287/directory-to-array-with-php/2120496#2120496

Comment: @Marco: the link you provided is not working anymore. I found a [benchmark at phparch.com](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/) in case someone is interested.

Comment: @Lando: interesting link. I hate when moderator here on SO deletes old questions that are very useful and it's not even possible to sse them anymore.

Comment: +1 for most complete answer for this and related (duplicate) questions

Comment: The Benchmark-question has vanished from Stackoverflow. Archive.org has it, however https://web.archive.org/web/20100922121105/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120287/directory-to-array-with-php/2120496#2120496

Answer (score 18):

The [Paolo Bergantino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) was fine but is now outdated!
Please consider the below official ways to get the Files inside a directory.

---

### [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/class.filesystemiterator.php)

`FilesystemIterator` has many new features compared to its ancestor `DirectoryIterator` as for instance the possibility to avoid the statement `if($file->isDot()) continue;`. See also the question [Difference between `DirectoryIterator` and `FilesystemIterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532064).

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__);
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() , PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

### [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

This snippet lists PHP files in all sub-directories.

```
$dir   = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__);
$flat  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$files = new RegexIterator($flat, '/\.php$/i');
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file , PHP_EOL;
}
```

See also the [Wrikken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3321905/938111).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time I imagine you want to skip `.` and `..`. Here is that with
recursion:

```
<?php
$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_dir);
foreach ($o_iter as $o_name) {
   echo $o_name->getFilename();
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator

Answer (score 0):

The old way would be:

```
<?php
    $path = realpath('.'); // put in your path here
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");
    $directories = array();
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
        $directories[] = $file;
    closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

As already mentioned the directory iterator might be the better way for PHP 5.