# PHP - Loop through files on server and run script for each file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I will try to explain as well as possible what I'm trying to do.

I have a folder on a server with about 100 xml files. These xml files are content pages with text and references to attachment filenames on the server that will be pushed to a wiki through an API.

It's all working fine 1 XML file at a time but I want to loop through each one and run my publish script on them.

I tried with opendir and readdir and although it doesn't error it only picks up the one file anyway.

Could someone give me an idea what I have to do. I'm very new to PHP, this is my first PHP project so my code is probably not very pretty!

Here's my code so far.

**The functions that gets the XML content from the XML file:**

```
<?php
function gettitle($file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmltitle = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="HEADLINE"]/string');
    return $xmltitle[0];
}

function getsummary($file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmlsummary = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="summary"]/string');
    return $xmlsummary[0];
}

function getsummarymore($file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmlsummarymore = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="newslinetext"]/string');
    return $xmlsummarymore[0];
}

function getattachments($file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $xmlattachments = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="attachment"]/string');
    return $xmlattachments[0];
}
?>
```

**Here's the main publish script which pushes the content to the wiki:**

```
<?php
// include required classes for the MindTouch API
include('../../deki/core/dream_plug.php');
include('../../deki/core/deki_result.php');
include('../../deki/core/deki_plug.php');

//Include the XML Variables
include('loadxmlfunctions.php');

//Path to the XML files on the server
$path = "/var/www/dekiwiki/skins/importscript/xmlfiles";

// Open the XML file folder 
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

// Loop through the files
while ($xmlfile = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
if($xmlfile == "." || $xmlfile == ".." || $xmlfile == "index.php" )
    continue;

//Get XML content from the functions and put in the initial variables
$xmltitle = gettitle($xmlfile);
$xmlsummary = getsummary($xmlfile);
$xmlsummarymore = getsummarymore($xmlfile);
$xmlattachments = getattachments($xmlfile);

//Build the variables for the API from the XML content

//Create the page title - replace spaces with underscores
$pagetitle = str_replace(" ","_",$xmltitle);

//Create the page path variable
$pagepath = '%252f' . str_replace("'","%27",$pagetitle);

//Strip HTML from the $xmlsummary and xmlsummarymore
$summarystripped = strip_tags($xmlsummary . $xmlsummarymore, '<p><a>');
$pagecontent = $summarystripped;

//Split the attachments into an array
$attachments = explode("|", $xmlattachments);

//Create the variable with the filenames
$pagefilenames = '=' . $attachments;

$pagefilenamefull = $xmlattachments;

//Create the variable with the file URL - Replace the URL below to the correct one
$pagefileurl = 'http://domain/skins/importscript/xmlfiles/';

//authentication
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

// connect via proxy
$Plug = new DreamPlug('http://domain/@api');
// setup the deki api location
$Plug = $Plug->At('deki');

//authenticate with the following details
$authResult = $Plug->At('users', 'authenticate')->WithCredentials($username, $password)->Get();
$authToken = $authResult['body'];
$Plug = $Plug->With('authtoken', $authToken);

// Upload the page content - http://developer.mindtouch.com/Deki/API_Reference/POST:pages//%7Bpageid%7D//contents
$Plug_page = $Plug->At('pages', '=Development%252f' . $pagetitle, 'contents')->SetHeader('Expect','')->Post($pagecontent);

// Upload the attachments - http://developer.mindtouch.com/MindTouch_Deki/API_Reference/PUT:pages//%7Bpageid%7D//files//%7Bfilename%7D
for($i = 0; $i < count($attachments); $i++){
    $Plug_attachment = $Plug->At('pages', '=Development' . $pagepath, 'files', '=' . $attachments[$i])->SetHeader('Expect','')->Put($pagefileurl . $attachments[$i]);
}

}

//Close the XMl file folder
closedir($dir_handle);

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the Files inside a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To traverse a directory of XML files you can just do:

```
$files = glob("$path/*.xml");

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    $xmltitle = gettitle($xml);
    $xmlsummary = getsummary($xml);
    $xmlsummarymore = getsummarymore($xml);
    $xmlattachments = getattachments($xml);
}
```

I also recommend you make a minor adjustment to your code so simplexml doesn't need to parse the same file four times to get the properties you need:

```
function gettitle($xml)
{
    $xmltitle = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="HEADLINE"]/string');
    return $xmltitle[0];
}

function getsummary($xml)
{
    $xmlsummary = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="summary"]/string');
    return $xmlsummary[0];
}

function getsummarymore($xml)
{
    $xmlsummarymore = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="newslinetext"]/string');
    return $xmlsummarymore[0];
}

function getattachments($xml)
{
    $xmlattachments = $xml->xpath('//var[@name="attachment"]/string');
    return $xmlattachments[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try your code as well. And thanks for the tips on the functions that will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your while loop to and see if that helps out better:

```
while (false !== ($xmlfile = readdir($dir_handle)))
```

Let me know.

#### EDIT:

By using the old way, there could have been a directory name that could have evaluated to false and stopped the loop, the way I suggested is considered the right way to loop over a directory while using `readdir` taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know.