# How to use RecursiveDirectoryIterator with a Modified Date filter?

Tags: php, regex, directory

I'm trying to read all the files on our servers(>2M files) and have made great headway using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321547/help-using-regexiterator-in-php), to filter it down to only PHP and HTML files with Regex.  My days have been trying to replicate that filtering for the file's modification or creation time instead of filename with this [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), but can't seem to find a way to pass the date I want to compare to.

Here's my working starting point:

```
abstract class FilesystemRegexFilter extends RecursiveRegexIterator {
    protected $regex;
    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $it, $regex) {
        $this->regex = $regex;
        parent::__construct($it, $regex);
    }
}
class FilenameFilter extends FilesystemRegexFilter {
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isFile() || preg_match($this->regex, $this->getFilename()));
    }
}
class DirnameFilter extends FilesystemRegexFilter {
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isDir() || preg_match($this->regex, $this->getFilename()));
    }
}

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("c:\\www");
$filter = new DirnameFilter($directory, '/^(?!cache)/');
$filter = new FilenameFilter($filter, '/\.(?:php|inc)$/');
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter) as $filename => $file) {
    echo $filename . PHP_EOL;
}
```

And this is the "pseudo-code" that I'm trying to accomplish by copying/pasting the code for using Regex.

```
abstract class FilesystemDateFilter extends RecursiveSOMEKINDOFIterator {
    protected $earliest_date;
    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $it, $earliest_date) {
        $this->earliest_date = $earliest_date;
        parent::__construct($it, $earliest_date);
    }
}
class FiledateFilter extends FilesystemDateFilter {
    // Filter files against the Earliest Date
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isFile() || $this->getMTime() >= $this->earliest_date );
    }
}

$filter = new FilenameFilter($filter, '/\.(?:php|inc)$/');
$filter = new FiledateFilter($filter, '2012-12-31');
```

**The problem is that only valid Regex can be used in the example code** and with other classes that I've tried, a 2nd argument is not allowed in it's construction.  I can't seem to figure out the correct alternative to `RecursiveRegexIterator` that will allow me to pass a date value to compare for the filter to include on PHP/HTML files created/modified in the last week.

Comment: Rather then trying to cram it into a `RecursiveRegexIterator`, have you thought about just using a `RecursiveFilterIterator` instead?

Comment: You don't need to pass it to, parent::__construct($it, $earliest_date); so you can use `RecursiveFilterIterator`

Comment: Would love to do that....am new to this whole iterator thing, and the example I started with used Regex to filter the files.  That saved substantial processing time, so started up the learning curve from code that I knew was working.  I googled what you were suggesting, but terms like "filter" "new" "files" with iterator doesn't exactly return anything specific or usable when you're trying to learn how it works.

Comment: Just try `class FiledateFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator`, declare a `public $earliestdate`, set it afterwards (not in its constructor parameter, as signatures shouldnt change). and see how that goes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you may try this example:

```
class FilesystemDateFilter extends RecursiveFilterIterator 
{
  protected $earliest_date;

  public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $it, $earliest_date) 
  {
      $this->earliest_date = $earliest_date;
      parent::__construct($it);
  }

  public function accept() 
  {
      return ( ! $this->isFile() || $this->getMTime() >= $this->earliest_date );
  }

  public function getChildren() 
  {
      return new static ( $this->getInnerIterator ()->getChildren (), $this->earliest_date );
  }   
}

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("c:\\www");
$filter = new FilesystemDateFilter($directory, strtotime('2012-12-31'));

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter) as $filename => $file) {
   echo $filename . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php returns timestamp so you need also give it.

What you was missing was overwriting `getChildern` which passes parameter down to to children.

Comment: Oh God, you don't want to see the horrible mess I came up with to accomplish this.  To also filter the filenames, will I be able to immediately then execute "$filter = new FilenameFilter($filter, '/\.(?:php|inc)$/');" from the original example?  I'm going to try it shortly, just want to know if it's possible, or whether to build that into the example you've given.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question but you can use it together with your example, your regex search is fine.

Comment: Am stuck with this though:  they both refer to  $this, which doesn't have getMTime() - how to access ->getMTime() from the accepti function?

Comment: I am getting time in accept function without problems, because it's DirectoryIterator, just it's timestamp though, i have updated example.

Comment: Alas, I'm using PHP 5.2.  Need some time to set up a 5.3environment...thank you though.

Comment: I don't think it's 5.3 related only static binding was not supported so change `new static` to `new self` in getChildren method.