# Playing a bunch of MP3s

Tags: html

My dad asked me to rip a few CDs the other day, and he wants to be able to play them from anywhere.  I thought the best way to do this would be to host them on my server and have a script show all the MP3s and he can select one, or multiple and click a play button.  There don't seem to be any apps like that, that are simple to use.  You can play music files without a special script, but is there anyway to play multiple in a row?  For example I have a page, "music.html" with a button "Beatles."  Could I play all the songs under /beatles/ and then return to that HTML file?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The best way would be to open him an account with a file sync service like Google Drive or Dropbox, and put the files in there. Your idea, while it may work, won't be as intuitive to use as the device's native file-access.

Comment: My mom also wants to play these music files, and she has a Google Chromebook she would like to play them all, I just checked and you cannot play the MP3 files from Google Drive, and neither could play the songs one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but not through HTML alone.
**Javascript/Jquery** can be used to play the songs. **PHP** (or some other server-side language) can crawl your server's directories to find music.
If you have metadata with artists and albums you could search for songs in an album or by a specific artist and have a server-side language serve a list of them up to your **Javascript** music player.

If none of this makes sense to you, then you should probably use the server as a file sharer (like Dropbox or Google drive). This will allow your parents to download the files and play them from their own computers.

-OR-

You could learn the cool stuff involved with creating your own functional, music-streaming web-server!

If you decide to go with the second option, here are some links to get you started.

[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/)-is a Jquery media player with some pretty cool functionality.  It allows you to play music or videos either individually or as a playlist.

[ID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)- is a PHP media file parser. It can find the metadata of songs such as the artist, band, bpm, etc.

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php)-is a [pretty powerful scripting language](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php).  In your case, it can allow you to go through your server's directories to find music files (which can be further filtered using ID3).  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322641/1911676) for more information on finding files in directories with php.

I hope this helps, whether you decide to try to build your own media streaming server or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can store songs' paths in a javascript array and play them one after another in a foreach loop. Check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp. Audio element has a "src" attribute you can set and a "play" function to start playing that song.

By the way not all browsers support playing mp3 files natively, you may need to convert them to another format. Check http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp to see which browser supports which file format natively.