# Check for files with PHP

Tags: php, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Get the Files inside a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086105/get-the-files-inside-a-directory)

Is there a function that can be used to get the contents of a directory (a photo gallery directory for example)?

I'm trying to save time on a project by automating a photo gallery based on which files are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the DirectoryIterator:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('path/to/images');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}
```

or alternatively glob():

```
$filenames = glob('path/to/images/*.jpg');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    echo $filename ."\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 glob() eh? awesome my friend!

Comment: I've opted for glob(). Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @shane note that as of PHP5.3, there is also a [`GlobIterator`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

I use a while loop to grab a list of files, omit the 2nd `if statement` if you want to grab a  all files.

```
if ($handle = opendir('/photos/')) {
  while(false !== ($sFile = readdir($handle))) {
     if (strrpos($sFile, ".jpg") === strlen($sFile)-strlen(".jpg")) {
        $fileList[] = $sfile;
     }
  }
}
```